# How to use comparison in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use comparison in bash, but just can't make it work.

```
#!/bin/bash
str="75.00 W, 170.00 W"
function str_check {
    pow_array=()
    regexp='([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+[[:space:]]W,[[:space:]]([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+[[:space:]]W'
    [[ $str =~ $regexp ]] && for (( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )); do
        pow_array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}")
    done
    if [ "$1" -lt ${pow_arr[1]} ]; then
        echo "Available power limit is ${pow_array[0]}"
        echo "Setting up ${pow_array[1]}"
    elif [ "$1" -gt "${pow_arr[2]}" ]; then
        echo "Available power limit is ${pow_array[0]}"
        echo "Setting up ${pow_array[2]}"
    else
        echo "All good, setting up $1"
    fi
}

str_check "70"
str_check "100"
str_check "200"
```

Already have tried '[[', '((' '[', qoute and unquote everething, but getting all kind of errors or wrong results. Need someone to give me a hand.

> ./t.sh: line 9: [: 70: unary operator expected
>
> ./t.sh: line 12: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: Running with `bash -x yourscript`, to log each command as it's run, might also have helped diagnose this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time to discover [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) !

```
Line 9:
    if [ "$1" -lt ${pow_arr[1]} ]; then
                  ^-- SC2154: pow_arr is referenced but not assigned (did you mean 'pow_array'?).
                  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Change all the references to `pow_arr` into `pow_array` and [it works !](http://ideone.com/w9WDkt)

Comment: Heh. An excellent answer, but also one that argues for the question to be closed as typo-based.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's right ! I'll throw the first close vote :)

Comment: Oh. My. God. I can't belive it was that simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: @kusayu no problem :)

Comment: @kusayu Also, if `$str` does not match `$regexp`, `pow_array` will be empty, and hence the comparisons to its elements will fail.

Comment: @GordonDavisson if it will happen, the whole script will not work because there are no NVIDIA cards installed and there is nothing to overclock. I can live with it )